# Is non-linear least squares the best approximation of the corresponding population conditional expectation in a least squared error sense?

Tags: econometrics, nonlinear-regression, conditional-expectation

**Background**

Loosely adapting Angrist & Pischke Mostly Harmless Econometrics (A&P) section 3.1, suppose we have a conditional expectation function (CEF) $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]$ defined such that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i=x\right]\equiv\int t f_y\left(t|X_i=x\right)dt
$$
A&P prove that given the OLS problem (3.1.2)
$$
\beta \equiv argmin_b \mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y_i-X_i' b\right)^2\right]
$$
$X_i'\beta$ provides the minimum least squared error to the CEF, that is (3.1.4)
$$
\beta = argmin_b \mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-X_i'b\right)^2\right\}
$$
I won't walk through their proof here since I'm basically going to follow it as part of the question below.

**Question**

Can the above be adapted to motivate the use of non-linear least squares?

Here is my attempt. Consider the below non-linear least-squares problem
$$
\vartheta\equiv argmin_\theta \mathbb{E}\left[\left(Y_i-g(X_i,\theta)\right)^2\right]
$$
where $g(X_i,θ)$ is assumed continuous but *not* necessarily differentiable.

Then adapting A&P 3.1.4 and its corresponding proof, it is also true that $g(X_i,\vartheta)$ provides the minimum least-squares approximation to $\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]$ among all parameter choices, that is,
$$
\vartheta = argmin_\theta \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-g(X_i,\theta)\right)^2\right]
$$
This is true because
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(Y_i-g(X_i,\theta)\right)^2 &= \left[\left(Y_i-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]\right)+\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-g(X_i,\theta)\right)\right]^2 \\
&=\left(Y_i-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]\right)^2\\
&+\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-g(X_i,\theta)\right)^2\\
&+\left(Y_i-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]\right)\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-g(X_i,\theta)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
The first term of the final expansion is not a function of the parameters $\theta$. The last term is zero by iterated expectations
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(Y_i-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]\right)\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-g(X_i,\theta)\right)\right\}\\
 &= \mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]\right)\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Y_i|X_i\right]-g(X_i,\theta)\right)\right\}\\
&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Is the above reasoning correct? Does it motivate non-linear least squares?

Also would be great to have a citation, but any help is appreciated.